# Jenkins hangs running cmd that calls tera term

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have a test.cmd file(does some tests and calls teraterm) that runs correctly on both command console and powershell console

When I try to call this .cmd file with Jenkins, script runs but Jenkins hangs.
There is specific foo_hangs.cmd script that always hangs the test, if this script is removed Jenkins does not freeze.

I tried calling the foo_hangs.cmd with "*Call*", script failed to execute

I tried calling the foo_hangs.cmd as below , script ran but Jenkins hangs..

- start /wait CMD /c "foo_hangs.cmd"
- start /wait CMD /k "foo_hangs.cmd"
- start CMD /c "foo_hangs.cmd"
- start CMD /k "foo_hangs.cmd"
- powershell -Command "Start-Process 'foo_hangs.cmd'"

test script is called from Jenkins execute Windows Batch command using below command

```
cmd /c D:\foo\test.cmd
```

test.cmd script is looks like this

```
d:
cd D:\foo
start /wait "test1" CMD /c "foo_nothangs.cmd"
start /wait timeout 10
start /wait "test2" CMD /c "foo_hangs.cmd" -- after this line test starts and ends successfully but hangs Jenkins
start /wait timeout 10
```

Comment: You use `Call` to run one Windows Batch File/Windows Command Script from another, e.g. `Call "foo_hangs.cmd"`. You can then remove all of the `timeout.exe` command lines, as the line following each `Call` will not run until the `call`ed script has completed. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to read its usage information.

Comment: For a more complete example of your submitted script, rewritten: **1.** `@CD /D "D:\foo" 2>NUL || Exit /B`, **2.** `@Call "foo_nothangs.cmd"`, **3.** `@Call "foo_hangs.cmd"`. Or depending upon the content of your `call`ed scripts, **1.** `@Call "D:\foo\foo_nothangs.cmd"`, **2.** `@Call "D:\foo\foo_hangs.cmd"`, Or even, **1.** `@(Call "D:\foo\foo_nothangs.cmd"`, **2.** `Call "D:\foo\foo_hangs.cmd")`. What you should however be aware of, is that none of your `call`ed script should run the command `Exit`, without it having the `/B` option.

Comment: Hi @Compo thanks for fast reply. If I use call, I receive: TeraTerm Macro: Error. Link macro first. Use 'connect' macro.  
This happens even for the 1st cmd script that does not hang. (foo_nothangs.cmd)

Comment: Interested parties, and I, cannot support you with issues regarding content of scripts which you've not submitted within your question. I've told you what the correct commands are for the information you've submitted, any further assistance requires that you play your part in that process, by submitting all of the information we need to assist you.

Comment: I agree with your points but I am afraid we are missing the main point. Those scripts run without issue on the Command Prompt or PowerShell. The issue is running them on Jenkins, which also works but hangs Jenkins

Comment: The main point is that scripts you are `call`ing are returning error messages, and instead of understanding that those errors are irrespective of the `call` command, you think otherwise. If you do not submit the content of those files, and/or any other content of your batch file/command script up to the point of that `call` command, then we are unable to assist you further. The choice is yours to make, so please take time to consider it.